# pre-installed .NET frameworks on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8

Will Windows 8 come with a pre-installed support for .NET framework 2.0? 
if not, What's the minimum supported "out of the box"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Windows 8 has .NET Framework 2.0 preinstalled; however, it is not enabled by default. To enable .NET Framework 2.0, go to Control Panel - Programs - Turn Windows features on or off and mark the .NET Framework 3.5 checkbox. Note that .NET Framework 3.5 includes .NET Framework 2.0.

```
.NET Framework 1.1: Windows Server 2003 
.NET Framework 2.0: Windows Server 2003 R2 
.NET Framework 3.0: Windows Vista, Windows Server 2008
.NET Framework 3.5 SP1: Windows 7, Windows Server 2008 R2
.NET Framework 4.0: Windows 8
.NET Framework 4.5: Windows 8
.NET Compact Framework 1.0 (SP2): Windows Mobile 5.0 
.NET Compact Framework 2.0: Windows Mobile 6.0 
 Mono 1.1.13.6: Ubuntu Dapper (6.06 LTS)
 Mono 1.2.6: Ubuntu Hardy (8.04 LTS)
 Mono 2.4.2.3: Ubuntu Karmic (9.10)
 Mono 2.4 branch snapshot: Ubuntu Lucid (10.04 LTS)
 Mono 2.6.7: Ubuntu Maverick (10.10), Ubuntu Natty (11.04)
```

Check this link:- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973853.aspx

Check this [link](http://www.febooti.com/downloads/automation-workshop/net/) for installing the 2.0 framework

Comment: FYI - if anyone is looking for a good reference on which .NET Framework version comes pre-installed with an OS, check out... https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2007/03/14/mailbag-what-version-of-the-net-framework-is-included-in-what-version-of-the-os/

Answer (score 3):

[Windows is not a .NET Framework delivery vehicle](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/04/04/10149346.aspx). You must be prepared for the case that the version of the .NET Framework you require is not already installed.

Comment: :- I think on Windows 8 .Net Framework is preinstalled but it is not enabled by default. :)

Comment: Naturally, I just wanted to know if 2.0 was available on it out of the box and without pro-active user steps required. turns out it's not. Thanks.